# Connection-level error: UNEXPECTED_FRAME hutch

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, rack, bunny

I have producers that produce message in fanout manner via hutch where consumers to consume those message. 
Here I have a single RabbitMq server where multiple instances for hutch runs.

Everything works fine in local/testing environment, but the hutch instance get crash in production(every hour) raising error

```
/home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/bunny-1.7.0/lib/bunny/concurrent/continuation_queue.rb:25:in `pop': Connection-level error: UNEXPECTED_FRAME - expected content body, got non content body frame instead (Bunny::UnexpectedFrame)
from /home/deploy/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/bunny-1.7.0/lib/bunny/concurrent/continuation_queue.rb:25:in `block in poll'
```

After searching through numerous posts here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, I've come to understand that this error has to do with a race condition.

BUT I didn't found any solution implemented for [hutch](https://github.com/gocardless/hutch).

I will be glad enough if someone help me here.

**Prerequisite:**

- RabbitMQ 3.3.4
- hutch (0.15.0)

  - bunny (>= 1.7.0)
  - carrot-top (~> 0.0.7)
  - multi_json (~> 1.5)

Comment: There have been some fixes on that area on the latest bunny releases. Perhaps upgrade to 2.0+ See https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#non-blocking-writes